# How to fix error: Web with blank space at bottom

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Please help to fix this error Web with blank space at bottom
Link: [http://www.khohanghoa.com](http://www.khohanghoa.com/)

I spent all day time to search and try to fix.

I tried set CSS

```
body {
 font-size: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0  }
```

but, it did not change

So, please help me

Thanks so much!

Comment: u have to remove div after fb-root div from footer file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please apply top:0px on this div tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <div style="left: -9999px; position: absolute;">
```

change this to like.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <div style="left: -9999px; position: absolute;top:0px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the body css to the below and the white spacing would go away.

```
body {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:relative` in `foundation.css` at line 384

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the follwing css it works fine[image]

```
media="all"
        body {
        background: white;
        color: #777777;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        position: relative; // delete this css 
        cursor: default;
        }
```